# Ignore null in Java stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I am performing some transformations using a Java stream on some data. I would like to ignore any values in a map that contain a null value.

Example:

```java
HashMap<String, Object> vals = new HashMap<>();
vals.put("null", null);
vals.put("string1", "1 ");
```

I've tried using filter:

```java
Map<String, Object> nullMap = vals.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue() != null)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            e -> e.getKey().trim(),
            e -> (e.getValue() instanceof String ? ((String) e.getValue()).trim() : e.getValue())))
```

However the returned object has the null key/value pair (in my example "null" -> null) completely removed. How can I retain the key "null" and ignore it during any subsequent processing after the `.filter` step in the Java stream?

In the above example I would like to get a Map returned with where the key and value pairs are trimmed and the null value is 'ignored' during the trimming step.

Comment: This code does not compile. `filter` does not return a `Map`. You should clarify what “subsequent processing” you want to perform, especially when you assume its result to be a map with the same content as the source map. Producing that map looks like an obsolete operation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Holger I've added a bit more detail to the question.

Comment: So just remove the `filter` step? `e.getValue() instanceof String` will evaluate to `false` for `null`, so it will not call `trim()`…

Comment: Thanks @Holger the code without the filter step raises a null pointer exception.

Comment: Ah, because the `toMap` collector does not allow `null` values in general. This is not a Stream issue, but an issue of this collector. Is applying `trim()` to the keys necessary? It doesn’t seem so in your example, but changing keys may cause ambiguity.

Comment: @Holger To be more specific, it the `Map.merge` that doesn't allow null value (`toMap` internally uses `Map.merge`)

Comment: @user7 it uses in Java 8. But since Java 9, the `toMap` collector without a merge function doesn’t use `Map.merge` internally. But it still retains the behavior of throwing for `null` values.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `toMap` collector does not allow `null` values, so you can’t use it to produce a `Map` containing `null` values.

If your input map is mutable and changing it is an option, you could trim the values as simple as

```
HashMap<String, Object> vals = new HashMap<>();
vals.put("null", null);
vals.put("string1", "1 ");

vals.replaceAll((key,val) -> val instanceof String? ((String)val).trim(): val);
```

If modifying the source map is not an option or you really have to trim the keys to, you have to use a different collector. You could define a collector ad-hoc, e.g.

```
HashMap<String, Object> result = vals.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(HashMap::new, (m,e) -> m.put(e.getKey().trim(),
        e.getValue() instanceof String? ((String)e.getValue()).trim(): e.getValue()),
        Map::putAll);
```

For better readability, i.e. to avoid repeating the same expression, we may use the block lambda syntax and a local variable, like

```
HashMap<String, Object> result = vals.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(
        HashMap::new,
        (m,e) -> {
            Object value = e.getValue();
            m.put(e.getKey().trim(), value instanceof String? ((String)value).trim(): value);
        }, Map::putAll);
```

Mind that when applying `trim()` to the keys, the keys may clash even when they were unique in the original map, e.g. when having `" key1"` and `"key1 "`. The `toMap` collector would throw in such scenarios whereas the ad-hoc collector created above would simply overwrite one of the conflicting mappings without a warning.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks for such a detailed answer, really helpful!